# Locking table for more transactions

Tags: sql, oracle, data-warehouse, locks

I am using Oracle 11g.

I am trying to realize scenario of concurrent loading into a table with index rebuild. I have few flows which are trying to realize this scenario:
1. load data from source,
2. transform the data,
3. turn off the index on DWH table,
4. load data into DWH,
5. rebuild index on DWH table.
I turn off and rebuild indexes for better performance, there are situations where one flow is rebuilding the index while the other tries to turn it off. What I need to do is to place some lock between points 2 and 3, which would be released after point 5.

Oracle built in `LOCK TABLE` mechanism is not sufficient, as the lock is released by the end of transaction, so any `ALTER` statement releases the lock.

The question is how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. What I wanted to do can be easily achieved using DBMS_LOCK package.

```
1. DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(...)
2. ALTER INDEX ... UNUSABLE
3. Load data
4. ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD
5. DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMS_SCHEDULER:

1. run jobs that load and transform the data
2. turn off indexes
3. run jobs that load data into DWH
4. rebuild indexes

[image]

Using Chains:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse009.htm#CHDCFBHG

Comment: That would require rather serious change in current architecture, I need to solve that one using locks.

Comment: Can you create table of states. Some procedures/SQL will not run if previous step is not finished. Perhaps you have table with logs? It would work just fine.

Comment: You can create jobs dynamically without interfering the "architecture". 1) create job. 2) run it. 3) Drop the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to range partition your table on minutes/hours basis of insertion time and enable indexes only when time is up. Each partition should have all indexes disabled after creation. Only one process can enable indexes.